# Javascripts sets: What's the difference between Set.prototype.values()and Set.prototype[@@iterator]()?

Tags: javascript, set

I've been looking into Javascript sets the last little bit (no one I know uses them at all). Some of the methods are the ones I always dreamed about with objects but I have a question about values vs @@iterator.

The documentation shows that they basically do the same things:

Set.prototype.values()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values

Set.prototype@@iterator 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/@@iterator

Can someone tell me why you would use one over another or are they basically the same (as it looks to me)?

Thank you! :)

Edit: Spelling

Comment: The same applies to `Arrays`, btw: `values` is an alias for the Iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not just "basically" the same, they are *exactly* the same:

```
Set.prototype.values === Set.prototype[Symbol.iterator] // true
```

You would use `.values()` when creating an iterator in your code explicitly. The `Symbol.iterator` method gets used implicitly in the [iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol), e.g. when you use a `for … of` loop on a set.

Fun fact: even `Set.prototype.keys` is exactly the same method, as "keys" and "values" coincide for sets. They exist mostly for consistency between the standard builtin collections (arrays, typed arrays, maps, sets), which all have `keys`, `values` and `entries` methods for creating the respective iterators. The `Symbol.iterator` provides an alias for one of them to select the default iteration behaviour.

Comment: Is there any reason to use over of the other?  It's seems bizarre that there's two methods for the same thing.  Backwards compatibility?

Comment: @Lloyd Calling it using `Symbol.iterator` is directly accessing the property. `values` is performing the high level operation that the value in the key `Symbol.iterator` represents. Calling it directly is basically exposing the implementation detail. No reason to ever call it directly when `values` already exists.

Comment: @andrew Hmm, interesting.  Thank you both!